# Flutter Dio multipart request image save name

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, dio

I'm using Dio for API calls. my question is I have chosen an image from the file and named as "path+flower.jpg". So in the Multipart request, we have one parameter **Filename**. While saving the image to S3 what will the image name flower.png or flower_one.jpg?

```
MultipartFile.fromFile("path+flower.png", filename: "flower_one.jpg"),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dio multipart request has:

**filePath** in which you can give path of image (it is required parameter)

**filename** is optional parameter

if you provide filename image will be saved with that filname

in your case image will be saved as:

> flower_one.jpg

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: i have edited my answer please let me know if you are still unclear

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

if you provide filename image will be saved with that filname

in your case image will be saved as:

flower_one.jpg